# Проигрывание аудио в Chrome с java сервера

Tags: java, google-chrome, аудио

Есть back-end на java. Который отдает файл следующим образом:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/get-record", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public byte[] getRecord()
{
    File file = _fileService.downloadCallRecord(new Call());
    try
    {
        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("problems");
    }

    return null;
}
```

На клиенте в chrome я принимаю его через html5 audio :

```
<audio controls loop>
    <source src="/test/get-record" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
```

Беру два браузера - Мозилла и Хром, получаю совершенно разное поведение. В Мозилле все отлично работает. В Chrome не работает перемотка.
Чем может быть обусловлено такое поведение в Chrome?

Если использую Uppod.js плеер, то ситуация повторяется.

UPD: Иду по ссылке на Uppod.js sample - http://html5player.ru/
Тут плеер работает корректно.

И если в src ставлю значение - "http://html5player.ru/sample.wav" то и на моей странице работает корректно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался в чем разница ответов, которые приходят из различных мест. Поставил нужные headers и заработало для html5 audio mp3.

```
public byte[] getRecord(HttpServletResponse response)
{
    File file = _fileService.downloadCallRecord(new Call());

    response.addHeader("Content-Type", "audio/mpeg");
    response.addHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");

    try
    {
        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("problems");
    }

    return null;
}
```